# Can't Publish to Secure Service Fabric Cluster via VSTS

Tags: azure, azure-devops, microservices, azure-service-fabric, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to deploy to a secure Service Fabric Cluster, installed on a network server, secured via certificates via VSTS, but I'm unable to.

I can connect via powershell from my dev machine, I can publish via Visual Studio but publishing via VSTS is not working.

I'm fairly sure it's a configuration issue when creating the 'Cluster Connection' in VSTS but not sure why?

The error I get is as follows:

```
2018-10-10T21:14:35.1844975Z Imported cluster client certificate with 
thumbprint 'd5df1g65d1fg651dfg651df6g51d6fg516d51651'.
2018-10-10T21:15:20.5985717Z ##[warning]Failed to contact Naming Service. 
Attempting to contact Failover Manager Service...
2018-10-10T21:16:00.6325833Z ##[warning]Failed to contact Failover Manager 
Service, Attempting to contact FMM...
2018-10-10T21:16:40.7508422Z ##[warning]No such host is known
2018-10-10T21:16:41.0348119Z Service fabric SDK version: 3.2.176.9494.
2018-10-10T21:16:41.7540933Z ##[error]No cluster endpoint is reachable, 
please check if there is connectivity/firewall/DNS issue.
```

Hoping someone has seen this before.

EDIT:

Note, I am able to deploy to this server via VSTS directly for IIS deployments, as an agent already exists and has been downloaded and configured with the appropriate proxy settings.

Comment: So I'm guessing adding a proxy switch somewhere is not feasible then... or possibly nobody has encountered this issue yet? Befuddling!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the message suggests:

> No cluster endpoint is reachable, 
>   please check if there is connectivity/firewall/DNS issue.

If your cluster is hosted on-premises, and the VSTS agent is hosted(Azure), you won't be able to deploy from the hosted agent to your localnetwork.

You will have to create a custom agent in a machine connected to your network.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Surely there is a way to add proxy settings in this scenario then. The server already has an agent downloaded and working for IIS deployments. That is, I can build in the 'Hosted' environment and then deploy after setting up a Deployment Group. I was hoping the setup would be similar, but strangely it seems to differ.

Comment: Whilst this is essentially the answer, it seems the process is flawed. If I can download an agent to the server by providing the proxy details during configuration and add the machine to a deployment group, surely a similar process should be in place to deploy an Azure Service Fabric application.

Comment: You don't need a similar process for Azure Because the cluster hosted in azure is accessible from the internet, in your case, the agent outside the network won't have access to the cluster.

Comment: No, it's an installation of an Azure Service Fabric cluster on a local server, behind the firewall. The same server with an existing agent on it that has deployments to IIS from a VSTS 'hosted' build server.